# Using an Environmental Variables In a Variety of Path Types

Tags: python, python-2.7, environment-variables

How would I go about using the same method for using the USERNAME variable in the top portion of code in the bottom code, I just feel like I don't have a grounded knowledge of the syntax with variables in in python yet:

Code:1

```
msg['Subject'] = os.environ['USERNAME'] #This is the working method i use to call upon    the USER NAME Variable.
```

Code:2

```
import os
os.makedirs.environ [("C:\Users\'USERNAME'\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\StartMenu\Programs\Data")]

#This is the path type that i don't know how to use the Environmental Variable's With, this would be my best guess at how this would be done.
```

Default Code with no edits:

```
import os
os.makedirs("C:\Users\'USERNAME'\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\StartMenu\Programs\Data)
```

Question:
So these two method's are working superbly:

```
import os
os.mkdir(os.path.expandvars("C:\\users\\%username%\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Data"))


import os
username = os.environ['USERNAME']
os.mkdirs("C:\Users\%s\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\StartMenu\Programs\Data" %    username)
```

But i'm Still a little confused on how to use the variable's that require 2 path's like Copy, Here's an Example:

```
copyfile(src, dst)

Or 

Copy(Src, dst)
```

P.S. I'm really curious what I should look into to start understanding the structure of scripts/ the rule's of thumb when it comes to the format you write them in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to expand the environment variables in the string, before you pass it to `os.mkdir` or `os.makedirs`. The function you want to use for that is `os.path.expandvars`. Also, environment variables in windows are delimited with the `%` character, not the `'` character.

So your code should look more like this:

```
import os
os.mkdir(os.path.expandvars("C:\\users\\%username%\\rest\\of\\path"))
```

Answer (score 2):

First try grabbing the username, then making the directory, like so:

```
import os

username = os.environ['USERNAME']
os.mkdirs("C:\Users\%s\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\StartMenu\Programs\Data" % username)
```

If you're looking to access the user's Start Menu, you may want to try `%APPDATA%` instead for better portability:

```
os.path.join(os.environ['APPDATA'], "Microsoft\Windows\StartMenu\Programs\Data")
```